# How to select data in same table on different line that are empty?

Tags: sql, select, sqlite

I have these three tables (I attach a preview). And of the end of list is example of data in table “virustotalscans.” There is column with name “virustotal.“ The each unique sample has number, for example 165, next sample has number 166 and etc.

TABLE **VIRUTOTALS**

```
CREATE TABLE virustotals (
                            virustotal INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                            virustotal_md5_hash TEXT NOT NULL,
                            virustotal_timestamp INTEGER NOT NULL,
                            virustotal_permalink TEXT NOT NULL
                    );
CREATE INDEX virustotals_md5_hash_idx
                    ON virustotals (virustotal_md5_hash);
```

TABLE **VIRUSTOTALSCANS**

```
CREATE TABLE virustotalscans (
                    virustotalscan INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    virustotal INTEGER NOT NULL,
                    virustotalscan_scanner TEXT NOT NULL,
                    virustotalscan_result TEXT
            );
CREATE INDEX virustotalscans_result_idx
                    ON virustotalscans (virustotalscan_result);
CREATE INDEX virustotalscans_scanner_idx
                    ON virustotalscans (virustotalscan_scanner);
CREATE INDEX virustotalscans_virustotal_idx
                    ON virustotalscans (virustotal);
```

TABLE **DOWNLOADS**

```
CREATE TABLE downloads (
                            download INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                            connection INTEGER,
                            download_url TEXT,
                            download_md5_hash TEXT
                            -- CONSTRAINT downloads_connection_fkey FOREIGN KEY (connection) REFERENCES connections (connection)
                    );
CREATE INDEX downloads_connection_idx   ON downloads (connection);
CREATE INDEX downloads_md5_hash_idx
                    ON downloads (download_md5_hash);
CREATE INDEX downloads_url_idx
                    ON downloads (download_url);
```

Example of data in table “virustotalscans”: http://pastebin.com/7E7McZwT

Now, I need select all samples, which are on all lines in column “virustotalscan_result” empty. So I need select all samples, which don´t detect VirusTotal with any antivirus. I tried this select:

```
select distinct downloads.download_md5_hash from virustotalscans, virustotals, 
   downloads 
where downloads.download_md5_hash = virustotals.virustotal_md5_hash and 
   virustotals.virustotal = virustotalscans.virustotal and 
   virustotalscans.virustotalscan_result IS NULL;
```

but I get MD5 hashes of all samples... Probably reason is that all samples contain at least one  line, which is empty. It is logical because, some antivirus always doesn’t detect some sample.

The better example: http://pastebin.com/y81DPpmQ. Now I need select sample - number (column virustotal), where are all lines empty in column virustotalscan_result. It can be for example only number 2.

Can you help me please?

Thank you very much for replies.

Comment: You seem to have a sample for only one table in your `pastebin`.  You may get better and faster responses if you recreate your sample tables in SQL Fiddle [http://sqlfiddle.com].

Comment: How do you define a `sample`?

Comment: Sample is defined with column virustotal in table VIRUSTOTALSCANS, this is number 165. It is one sample, next samples have other number. So the better example: http://pastebin.com/y81DPpmQ. Now I need select sample - number (column virustotal), where are all. lines in column virustotalscan_result empty. It can be for example number 2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT download_md5_hash
FROM downloads
JOIN virustotals ON download_md5_hash = virustotal_md5_hash
WHERE virustotal IN (SELECT virustotal
                     FROM virustotalscans
                     GROUP BY virustotal
                     HAVING COUNT(virustotalscan_result) = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it works correctly only for part behind NOT IN - select in brackets... So it works correctly only in the table virustotalscans.

Comment: Your comment lacks any information that would allow me to improve the answer.

Comment: I am sorry that I am writting after long time. If I use SELECT virustotal
                         FROM virustotalscans
                         GROUP BY virustotal
                         HAVING COUNT(virustotalscan_result) = 0)
It works, I get two correct virusotal values, that don´t detect any antivirus. But if I enter all select I get a lot of MD5 hashes, I have to interrupt listening... Can you help me please edit this select please?

Comment: Use `SELECT download_md5_hash, virustotal FROM ...`. Do you get any other than the two virustotal values?

Comment: Thanks, but if I use your modification I get the same result only with additional column - virustotal... :-( So I am getting all values, I have to intterupt listening... I need get only two correct values, that I get if I use only your select in brackets, but now I need get these values with their MD5 hashes...

Comment: And what are the values in the virustotal column? The two values from the correct subquery, or any others?

Comment: Values are others, but constantly repeated values virustotal - 2, 220, 467 and 24. Correct virustotal values are 59, 554. I get these two vaules if I use select in brackets. I check it with SELECT * FROM virustotalscans where virustotal='554'; and SELECT * FROM virustotalscans where virustotal='59';. All fileds are really empty. If I use SELECT * FROM virustotalscans where virustotal='220'; there are only few antiviruses that don´t detect it. (Few empty fields...)

Comment: I have never understood any of your explanations, but I guess `NOT IN` should have been `IN`.